# Program proccessing

Tags: c, memory, assembly, processor

So i found out that when the program executes the EIP pointer is set to the first instruction in the code segment, the processor does an execution loop:

1. Points the EIP to the first instruction
2. **Adds the byte length of the instruction to EIP**
3. Executes the instruction that was read in step 1
4. Back to 1

My question is, what happens in the step 2?

Please reply 
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have instructions like this:

```
0x1000 INSTR_1
0x1004 INSTR_2
0x1007 INSTR_3 /* instructions can have different size */
```

and the `EIP` contains 0x1000, you need to update the `EIP` to make it point to the second instruction (0x1004), so it can execute it in the next iteration. If you don't do this, you will always execute the first instruction.

Because instructions can have different size, you can't just add the constant to it (you can do that if all instructions have the same size, like in RISCs), but you need to add lenght of the instruction you've just read. So, after the first, you will add 4, to make it point to the second one, and after the second instruction, you will add 3 to `EIP` and it will point to the third instruction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can you please also explain to me about the instruction length? I've searched the net and the stuff is too technical, and I am sort of "new" to this. thank you.

Comment: @EvgenyDanilenko Instruction length is just the number of the bytes that instruction takes in memory where it is stored. In my example, INSTR_1 has length of 4, and INSTR_2 length of 3.

Comment: hmm I'm a little bit confused now, in my book it says 0x00fc45c7 is 4 bytes (word); 00[1]fc[2]45[3]c7[4]. in your example 0x1000 is 4 bytes but why isn't 0x1004 4bytes long? is it because when you add the instruction length it is then decremented by -1? im guessing that is why the INSTR_3 is 0x1007: 4-1=3 4+3=7 >>> 0x1007. am i right?

Thank you for you reply :))

Comment: @EvgenyDanilenko `0x1000` is just a memory address where the INSTR_1 is stored. Just imagine that INSTR_1 is 0x00fc45c7 and that this is stored starting at address 0x1000. It is important to know the address of the instruction, because EIP doesn't contain instruction data, but the address of the instruction (hence `Instruction POINTER`)

Comment: Thank you, this I understood, what i was asking was why the pointer to this memory address 0x1004 was incremented by 3 and not by 4? i mean 0x1000 and 0x1004 are 4 bytes in size. is it because that after the instruction length is added it is then decremented by -1?;

0x1000 (4 bytes therefore add 4 bytes to the EIP)
0x1004 (size 4 bytes. decremented by -1 > byte length is 3. EIP(0x1004+3))
0x1007

etc

Comment: @EvgenyDanilenko Ok, also imagine that INSTR_2 is 0xFC45EE - only three bytes long. You don't need to do any calculations with addresses - the instruction fetch phase will detect how many bytes it needs to fetch (usually, it will load the first byte, it will check some fields in the instruction, then it will load next byte and so on).

Comment: Ok, I'm derping a little. Looking back at your reply to my initial question can you explain how did you count the "after the first, you will add 4, to make it point to the second one, and after the second instruction, you will add 3 to EIP and it will point to the third instruction " Like, to me the byte length of 0x1000 is 4 and 0x1004 is also 4. why do we add 3 to EIP not 4?

Thank you

Comment: @EvgenyDanilenko No, 0x1000 and 0x1004 are just addresses, and not the real instruction data. The real instruction data is stored at these addresses.

Comment: Oh alright, so in the comment where you said that INSTR_1 is 4 and INSTR_2 is 3 bytes long, you basically  you made up the byte length? if so, then i understood everything.

Comment: Exactly. The actual byte length depends on the type of the instruction, and I've just made up the byte length for all instructions.

Answer (score 1):

EIP gets the address of next instruction.

Answer (score 1):

*"2. Adds the byte length of the instruction to EIP"*

Increments the EIP to point to next instruction, it is incremented by the no. of bytes taken up by the current instruction

Answer (score 1):

EIP move to the next instruction.

```
Points the EIP to the first instruction  

EIP-->     1.instruction 1 with 2 bytes 
           2.instruction 1 with 5 bytes
           3.instruction 1 with 3 bytes 



Adds the byte length of the instruction to EIP(move 2 bytes ahead)  

           1.instruction 1 with 2 bytes        
EIP-->     2.instruction 1 with 5 bytes
           3.instruction 1 with 3 bytes
```

Adds the byte length of the instruction to EIP(move 5 bytes ahead)

```
           1.instruction 1 with 2 bytes        
           2.instruction 1 with 5 bytes
EIP-->     3.instruction 1 with 3 bytes
```